# Setting a classes accessors correctly across a business logic layer?

Tags: c#, oop, visual-studio-2010, class-design

I have several classes within my business logic layer (some examples);

`Atomic.Core.BLL.Client`
`Atomic.Core.BLL.Airport`
`Atomic.Core.BLL.Airline`

When setting up the accessors on each class, I want to sometimes refer to objects within the BLL (as they are interlinked), but I want to do it efficiently and moreover with best practice.

I want to do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
//removed for brevity

namespace Atomic.Core.BLL.Airport
{
    public class Airport
    {
        private int airport_id = 0;
        public int AirportId
        {
            get { return airport_id; }
            set { airport_id = value; }
        }
        private Airline airline = null;
        public Airline Airline
        {
            get { return airline; }
            set { airline = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio says that my `AirlineObject` is a namespace being used as a type, which I totally understand, so can I add Airline to the Using list and shorthand it? How do I do that? `using Atomic.Core.BLL.Airline as Airline`? I can't remember!  Also, am I missing the point here and should I re-think what I am trying to do?

Help (as always) appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Airline = Atomic.Core.BLL.Airline;

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks tzup ;) Props to Craigt also, I'm going to move all the individual objects out of their own namespaces and into the BLL layer.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice - do not name namespace and a class with the same name. Reasons? Here are some:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four

Comment: Now this is a good point!  +1.  I only had my `Airline` object as airline for clarity. In my project it's actually called `AirlineObject`, but a very good point nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have all BLL classes in their own namespace. Dump them all into Atomic.Core.BLL, or a subsection - Atomic.Core.BLL.AiportLogic - if you need to be more specific.

Comment: I commented on Stilgar's post below regarding the same point.  My actual project code has the airline object called `AirlineObject`. +1 however for the help :)

Comment: ...I'd mark this as the answer also if I could because bringing the BLL objects down from their individual namespaces is a very good idea. Thanks again ;)